# Find the optimum combination

Tags: matlab, optimization

I am trying to optimise this: `function [ LPS, LCE ] = runProject( Nw, Np, Nb)` which calls some other functions I have written before. The idea is to find the optimum combination of `Nw`, `Np`, `Nb` AND keep the `LPS=0`, while `LCE` is minimum. `Nw`, `Np`, `Nb` should be positive integers. `LCE` will also be positive.

```
function [ LPS, LCE ] = runProject( Nw, Np, Nb)
%
%   Detailed explanation goes here

[Pg, Pw, Pp] = Pgener();

[Pb, LPS] = Bat( Pg );

[LCE] = Constr(Pw, Pp, Nb)

end
```

However, I tried the `gamultiobj` solver from the [Global Optimization Toolbox](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/global-optimization/features.html#multiobjective-genetic-algorithm-solver) of matlab2015 (trial version) for a different approach with pareto front, but I got the error: 
"Optimization running.
Error running optimization.
Not enough input arguments."

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, this question does not make any sense. Please include an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This will significantly increase your chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: Most likely you call the solver in a wrong way (perhaps you forgot an input argument), but you didn't include the call in your answer so it is hard to say anything usefull about it.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin I tried to post a pic, but I dont have the necessary reputation yet.

Comment: @vpapats If you upload it somewhere and put the link in the comments, someone with enough rep can put the picture in your question.

Comment: I hope this helps. [link](http://postimg.org/image/3m7umtghz/)

Answer (score 1):

You should write your objective function like the following example:

```
function scores = rastriginsfcn(pop)
%RASTRIGINSFCN Compute the "Rastrigin" function.
    % pop = max(-5.12,min(5.12,pop));
    scores = 10.0 * size(pop,2) + sum(pop .^2 - 10.0 * cos(2 * pi .* pop),2);
```

As you can see, the function accepts all the inputs as a single vector `pop`.

With such representation I can evaluate the function as follows:

```
rastriginsfcn([2 3])
>> ans
     13
```

Still for running the optimization from the toolbox you have to mention the number of variables, for instance, in my example it is equal to 2:

```
[x fval exitflag] = ga(@rastriginsfcn, 2)
```

It is the same for the multi-objective optimization. Check the following image from MATHWORKS:

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I got a bit confused with your answer. My background is weak, but now I have to stack with matlab. Is there any way to forward you my code? I believe the current structure drives me to these errors.

Comment: @vpapats I assume what you should do is pretty easy. Just present the input as a vector and the output as another. You need to just combine your variables to a vector. Otherwise, just add the real function to the question. People will help you.